# JIRA - Query filter to exclude stories with specific text in title

Tags: jira

```
User Story
    [My Project-121] - Incorrect time stamp format displayed on Login screen 
Sub tasks:
    [DEVELOPMENT] Documentation
    [DEVELOPMENT] Analysis & Design
    [DEVELOPMENT] Implementation
    [DEVELOPMENT] TESTING
```

All stories in our project basically has the above subtasks. I would like to create a filter that will only return all the stories but exclude the subtasks. Note that the subtasks themselves are also stories so i cant just say return all stories. The only option i see is to run a filter that excludes everything that has the text [DEVELOPMENT] in the title. The problem is im having trouble escaping the square bracket.

The closes i got is the following query:

```
project in ("My Project") and  Sprint in openSprints() and summary !~ DEVELOPMENT
```

The above works but it excludes the text `DEVELOPMENT` and not `[DEVELOPMENT]` meaning it might exclude some valid stories with the string `DEVELOPMENT`. I did try with the square brackets but i get an error in the escape character

```
project in ("My Project") and  Sprint in openSprints() and summary !~ \[DEVELOPMENT\]
```

How can i change the above so it excludes anything with a subtask with "`[DEVELOPMENT]`" in the title.  And is summary the correct field to check for this?

Answer (score 0):

Can you filter out subtasks using: type in standardIssueTypes() which will ignore subtasks. I think

Answer (score 0):

Try using an excluded term, instead of !~ use -

You can use NOT if you are already searching for text, but NOT cannot be used by itself.

https://confluence.atlassian.com/jira/performing-text-searches-185729616.html